# MySQL join with where clause

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have two tables I want to join.

I want all of the categories in the categories table and also all of the categories subscribed to by a user in the category_subscriptions table.

essentially this is my query so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN user_category_subscriptions 
     ON user_category_subscriptions.category_id = categories.category_id
```

This works fine however I want to add a where clause on the end of the query which then essentially makes it an inner/equi join.

```
   SELECT *
    FROM categories
    LEFT JOIN user_category_subscriptions 
         ON user_category_subscriptions.category_id = categories.category_id 
   WHERE user_category_subscriptions.user_id = 1
```

How do I get all the categories as well as all the categories subscribed to by a particular user using only one query?

category_id being a key in both categories table and user_category_subscriptions. user_id residing in the  user_category_subscriptions table.

thanks

Answer (score 349, accepted):

You need to put it in the `join` clause, not the `where`:

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN user_category_subscriptions ON 
    user_category_subscriptions.category_id = categories.category_id
    and user_category_subscriptions.user_id =1
```

See, with an `inner join`, putting a clause in the `join` or the `where` is equivalent. However, with an `outer join`, they are vastly different.

As a `join` condition, you specify the rowset that you will be joining to the table. This means that it evaluates `user_id = 1` first, and takes the subset of `user_category_subscriptions` with a `user_id` of `1` to join to all of the rows in `categories`. This will give you all of the rows in `categories`, while only the `categories` that this particular user has subscribed to will have any information in the `user_category_subscriptions` columns. Of course, all other `categories` will be populated with `null` in the `user_category_subscriptions` columns.

Conversely, a `where` clause does the join, and *then* reduces the rowset. So, this does all of the joins and then eliminates all rows where `user_id` doesn't equal `1`. You're left with an inefficient way to get an `inner join`.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 19):

Try this

```
  SELECT *
    FROM categories
    LEFT JOIN user_category_subscriptions 
         ON user_category_subscriptions.category_id = categories.category_id 
   WHERE user_category_subscriptions.user_id = 1 
          or user_category_subscriptions.user_id is null
```

Comment: I tried this solution in my case , the query executes successfully but the records does not filtered.

Answer (score 1):

This must work with `where` clause

Example:

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN user_category_subscriptions ON user_category_subscriptions.category_id = categories.category_id)tb where user_category_subscriptions.user_id = 1
```