# MySQL self-join with exclude where

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I'm looking for solution opposite [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219909/mysql-join-with-where-clause/).
I want to self-join tableA as tableB so where clause would not affect tableB result.
I want to get sum of all customers and sum of customers with cancel_date='0000-00-00'
I don't want to switch the places of the tables tableA and tableB. I do have other `where` and `select`  statements based on tableA.

```
SELECT 
count(tableA.client_id) as c_total, 
count(tableB.client_id) as all_c_total 
FROM (tableA) LEFT JOIN tableA tableB ON tableA.client_id = tableB.client_id
WHERE tableA.`cancel_date` = '0000-00-00' 
GROUP BY month(tableA.purch_date) 
ORDER BY month(tableA.purch_date)
```

The result should looks like this:

```
---------------------
c_total | all_c_total
---------------------
  251   | 273
  45    | 65
  12    | 15
  23    | 29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `RIGHT JOIN`, and move the conditional out of the `WHERE` clause into the join condition...

```
SELECT 
    count(t1.client_id) as c_total, 
    count(t2.client_id) as all_c_total 
FROM tableA t1 
    RIGHT JOIN tableA t2 
        ON t1.client_id = t2.client_id
        AND t1.`cancel_date` = '0000-00-00' 
GROUP BY month(t1.purch_date) 
ORDER BY month(t1.purch_date)
```

But... I'd suggest you reconsider, switch the order of the tables, and use a `LEFT JOIN` instead.  `LEFT JOIN` is considered better style and more readable than `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: all my select and where statements are based on tableA, so I considered that it would inappropriate switch tables up side down just because of the one extra column from tableB (all_c_total). And your answer didn't work ( cancel_date still affects both tables)

Comment: @castt Hmmm... I've updated my answer to alias both tables...  `cancel_date` shouldn't limit the results for `t2`, so if the updated query doesn't give you the expected results, there must be some other issue, in which case I would suggest posting sample data to go along with the expected results you provided.

Comment: @castt There should be no conditions in your `where` clause for `tableA t1`... this would turn your `outer join` into an `inner join`.  As far as the ordering of your tables in your `from` clause, I don't think this should be determined by which table has the most columns in your `select` statement... instead I think the ordering should be based on some sort of logical progression, starting with the required records (`t2`) and progressing to the optional records (`t1`)..

Comment: I see your point, but what if I want to have 3 'where' clause for both tables and one of those 'where' statements should not include t2? Does it make sense? Or my query-structure is wrong?