# MySQL join with 2 conditions error

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out why I get an SQL error with the mySQL statement (in php file) below. I think the problem relates to the second condition 'AGREEDPRODUCTS.productid_corporation is null'. I checked that the syntax of the used parameters is correct as used in the database. I also tried other alternatives with respect to the second condition (like using WHERE but that is obvious not allowed;[MySQL join with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219909/mysql-join-with-where-clause)) but those didn't work.

```
$sqlquery4 = "SELECT AGREEDPRODUCTS.id,AGREEDPRODUCTS.productid_supplier,EMETERPRODUCTS.productname "
                . "FROM AGREEDPRODUCTS "
                . "INNER JOIN EMETERPRODUCTS "    
                . "ON AGREEDPRODUCTS.productid_supplier=EMETERPRODUCTS.productid AGREEDPRODUCTS.producttype='EMETER' AND AGREEDPRODUCTS.productid_corporation is null "
                . "ORDER BY AGREEDPRODUCTS.productid_supplier";
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed an `AND`, or other separator, on that line:

```
ON AGREEDPRODUCTS.productid_supplier=EMETERPRODUCTS.productid AGREEDPRODUCTS.producttype='EMETER' AND AGREEDPRODUCTS.productid_corporation is null
                                                            ^^^
```

Comment: thnx (both). Feel very thick that I have overlooked that ;-(

Answer (score 0):

```
ON AGREEDPRODUCTS.productid_supplier=EMETERPRODUCTS.productid AND AGREEDPRODUCTS.producttype='EMETER' AND AGREEDPRODUCTS.productid_corporation is null
```

You're missing an `AND`........................................................................................^here^.

And you confused something here:

> like using WHERE but that is obvious not allowed

The WHERE in this question makes the left/right join to an inner join. That's why you have to put it in the join condition. A WHERE clause is always possible. You could as well also put your second join condition in a where clause.