# Join with where and contains clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not able to write a sql query where I need to join 2 tables and get the common value of both.

something like this,

```
select control_id from ProjectImage
where group_id ="20"
Join
(select images from coupon where coupon_name is "test" and images contains control_id of projectImage)
```

images is a list of contol_id's separated by comma's.

So in the end I want only those `control ids` which are present in the coupon's table image column.

```
ProjectImage table ---- 
         image_id   bigint(20)  
    control_id  varchar(255)
    name    varchar(255)
    project_id  bigint(20)      
    group_id    bigint(20)

Coupon table:
    id  bigint(20)  
    image   varchar(1250)   
    name    varchar(255)    
    status  int(11)     
    wafer_id    bigint(20)
```

Comment: select field from table1 join table 2 on <condition> where <condition> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: first, is it MySql or Sql Server? Second, joins should be before the where clause

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL join with where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219909/mysql-join-with-where-clause)

Comment: So the foreign key in coupon table is in the list of control_ids separated by comma? That is how you want to connect those 2 tables?

Comment: @RagingBull yes but i m not sure if thats possible

Answer (score 0):

you can join table on some key eg primary key or  you can use something like

```
select control_id from ProjectImage where group_id ="20" and
control_id contains(select images from coupon where coupon_name is
"test" and images contains control_id)
```

Comment: contains require column and text but here it is not able to resolve the second query

Answer (score 0):

if I get your question right, your query should probably look like this

```
SELECT ProjectImage.control_id, coupon.images
FROM ProjectImage
JOIN coupon ON ProjectImage.control_id = coupon.control_id
WHERE ProjectImage.group_id ="20"
    AND coupon.coupon_name = 'test'
```

If it does not work that way, please, provide us the table structure for ProjectImage and Coupon.

**Edit**
With the structure provided, you may follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows) and split the column image into separate rows and then use casual join, for example on a temporary table

Comment: there is nothing like coupon.control_id. there is no common column in both tables. the only thing is the control_id of projectImage table is a subset of images in coupon table.

Comment: @PSDebugger if there is no common column then you can not use join.

Comment: the only common things is the control_id is there in the images ( images is a collection of different id's where control_id will be one of them). So i need to compare if the control_id from projectImage table is there in the images column then return that.

Comment: @PSDebugger could you give us the table structure?

Comment: added in the question-

Comment: Referring to Zohar Peleds comment - what database are you using?

Comment: Anyway, I can't really think of anything more useful then using a 'LIKE' statement - will add to previous answer in a minute

Comment: Tried like. Its returning null. Using mysql db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82055/discussion-between-psdebugger-and-zax).