# A column parameter is ambiguous when I join two tables

Tags: sql, join

Both tables (zielpersonen and wegeinland) have a column named as WP. So when I join them, there is an error saying that the column reference "WP" is ambiguous. Actually I want to use WP coming from zielpersonen table for my calculations. How can I avoid this error?

```
SELECT SUM("WP"*"w_rdist")/(62868*AVG("WP"))  FROM mobility.mzmv2010.zielpersonen 
JOIN mobility.mzmv2010.wegeinland USING ("HHNR","ZIELPNR")
```

Comment: you need to provide explicitly by what field you are [joining tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). This is why you getting this error. Reference the manual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL join with where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219909/mysql-join-with-where-clause)

Comment: So which WP column do you want to use? Either specify `mobility.mzmv2010.zielpersonen.wp` or `mobility.mzmv2010.wegeinland.wp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, use aliases for your tables and then prefix the columns you want with the corresponding table aliases.

```
SELECT
    SUM(zp."WP"*"w_rdist")/(62868*AVG(zp."WP"))  
FROM mobility.mzmv2010.zielpersonen zp
JOIN mobility.mzmv2010.wegeinland wg 
    USING ("HHNR","ZIELPNR")
```

This is generally a best practice for when you're accessing more tables in a query, so make sure you prefix all of your columns in a query.

By doing this you're actually being a bit proactive since if there is a chance a column which is now in a single table will be added to your second table, this query will then fail and will require correction (which I guess is something you wouldn't want to happen in a production environment).

Answer (score 0):

You should use table aliases and qualified column names.  Not just in this query, but as a good habit:

```
SELECT SUM(p."WP" * "w_rdist")/ (62868 * AVG(p."WP"))
FROM mobility.mzmv2010.zielpersonen p JOIN
     mobility.mzmv2010.wegeinland w
     USING ("HHNR", "ZIELPNR")
```

I don't know where `w_rdist` comes from, but that should also have a table alias.