# optimization of query in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my production database performance issue.

My sql query is taking long time for executing so the how to optimize the following mysql query.

```
select sum(distributor_earning) as col_0_0_, sum(distributor_share) as col_1_0_ 
from my_transaction mytransac0_ 
cross join del_transaction deltran1_ 
cross join user user3_ 
where mytransac0_.del_transaction_id=deltran1_.id and deltran1_.agent_parent_id=user3_.id and deltran1_.trx_status=4 and user3_.username='xyz';
```

It gives following output

```
+-----------+-----------+
| col_0_0_  | col_1_0_  |
+-----------+-----------+
| 579239.27 | 630557.77 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

1 row in set (15.14 sec)

I have over 100k records.

IN where condition index is build in del_transaction_id

Comment: Guessing that "a record in lakhs" means that you have 100k records. Please don't use Indian words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Firstly, you should replace `WHERE` clause with `ON` clause.

```
select sum(distributor_earning) as col_0_0_, sum(distributor_share) as col_1_0_ 
from my_transaction mytransac0_ 
cross join del_transaction deltran1_ ON mytransac0_.del_transaction_id=deltran1_.id AND deltran1_.trx_status=4
cross join user user3_ ON deltran1_.agent_parent_id=user3_.id AND user3_.username='xyz';
```

For more details about the differences between `WHERE` and `ON`: [MySQL join with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219909/mysql-join-with-where-clause/1219924#1219924).

#### Secondly, you'd better create indexes on the columns involved in this query.

It will run much faster when you finish these two steps.

Answer (score 1):

Create views for improve perfomance

Refer [Is a view faster than a simple query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439056/is-a-view-faster-than-a-simple-query)

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever try sql indexing?
Try this query on your mysql

```
CREATE INDEX INDEX_FAST_2
ON user(id, username);
```

After succeeded then try to run your query again.