# Query to select the last entries per computer for a group from two tables

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am new to databases and I was given a task at work to improve an open source system that's been designed by someone else.

What I tried so far is:

```
select r.id, r.room_name, e.type,max(e.start_time) as st, max(e.end_time) as et ,max(e.timestamp) as updt
from mrbs_room r 
join mrbs_entry e on r.id=e.room_id 
where r.area_id=1 and r.disabled=0 
group by r.id
order by r.room_name DESC;
```

Snapshot of result:

[image: query]

The last field (Name) records results are not matching the database records.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL join with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219909/mysql-join-with-where-clause)

Comment: Hi there. Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Also, a number of folks in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they worry about people feeling excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.

Comment: The query in your image, and the text query provided, are not the same: there is no `max(e.name) as name` in the text version.