# Find value with many-to-many relationship table

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

There is 3 tables.

Book.
ID / Title

Author.
ID / Name

Book_Author.
Book_ID / Author_ID

The goal is to get all titles of books written by specific Author. We know the name of Author.
I've tried an approach with join but it takes two steps to reach result anyhow I try.

for example:

```
select book_author.book_id, book_author.author_id  
from  book_author 
inner join author on book_author.author_id = author.id 
where name = 'author1';

select book.title 
from  book 
inner join author_to_book on book.id = book_author.book_id 
where author_id = 3;
```

Have tried to merge the methods but with no success so far.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL join with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219909/mysql-join-with-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Try using SubQueries:

```
SELECT b.ID, b.Title 
FROM Book AS b 
WHERE b.Id = (SELECT ID FROM Author AS a WHERE a.Name = 'Author Name Here');
```

Comment: This won't work, it's missing the `book_author` table that links them.

Comment: `b.id` is a book ID, not the author ID.

Answer (score 0):

Join all 3 tables

```
SELECT b.title
FROM book AS b
JOIN book_author AS ba ON b.id = ba.book_id
JOIN author AS a ON a.id = ba.author_id
WHERE a.name = 'author1'
```